# String.format(%.2f,double) works only in half of the tests

Tags: java, parsing, formatting, double

I am trying to format double values, so it they would have only 2 decimal spaces:

```
remainingAmount = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f",remainingAmount - calculatePrincipalPayment()));
```

As you can see, this code formats double value `remainingAmount - calculatePrincipalPayment()` using `String.format()`, then transfers it from String to Double and assigns it to the double variable remainingAmount (which was declared). `remainingAmount` is double and `calculatePrincipalPayment()` returns double.

The problem is that it formats only part of the values, for example it can return 401.37 (which is the required formatting) as well as 403.71999999999997.
I also already tried to do formatting by using DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##").

Comment: `double` doesn't have a format, only strings do so parsing it doesn't do what you think.

Comment: If you run your code for `403.71999999999997` you get `403.72` Can you give an example which produces the output you mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO! First thing I notice is that you're going from a double to a string to a double in one line. There's no need to go to a string at all until you're finally ready to print. Edit your post to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code along with sample input and outputs so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `double` (or its boxed counterpart `Double`) has no capacity to store a specific format to be used when rendering as a String. It is just a raw value.

I suspect you believe that a `double` value obtained by parsing from a specific format somehow retains that format. This is not the case.

Floating point types are imprecise; not all values can be accurately stored. In cases where the exact value cannot be stored, the closest storable value is used - as is the case with some of your results.